# Composer autoload is overriding codeigniter autoload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using composer. Composer autoload file is in the application/vendor/autoload.php. In codeigniter 3 I set ["composer_autoload"] = true in config. But it is overriding the main autoload of the codeigniter and couldn't able to load the Main classes of codeigniter and my codeigniter libraries. What should i do?

Comment: https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2012/05/07/composer-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the config file there is comment like below just uncomment it.

```
spl_autoload_register( function ( $class ) {
    $file = "sources/" . $class . ".class.php";
    if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {
        require $file;
        return;
    }
} );
```

2. Make $config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
3. Then add ( require FCPATH . 'application/vendor/autoload.php'; ) below the spl_autoload_resgister function.